# A library should only be specified by its name?

Tags: cocoapods, specifications

I make a CocoaPods Spec and ask a pull request to its master repo, but my request didn't pass because :

```
Baidu-Map-iOS-SDK/2.1.1/Baidu-Map-iOS-SDK.podspec [Full]
Baidu-Map-iOS-SDK (2.1.1)
- ERROR | [iOS] A library should only be specified by its name
The spec cannot be accepted.
```

What's that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/blob/master/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/linter.rb):

```
def libraries_invalid?(libs)
    libs.any? { |lib| lib.end_with?('.a', '.dylib') || lib.start_with?('lib') }
end

def _validate_libraries(libs)
   if libraries_invalid?(libs)
     error "A library should only be specified by its name"
   end
end
```

So I guess you're either putting "lib" on the start of it or specifying an extension and you're not supposed to.

Comment: I think that is weird 。。。 "Baidu-Maps-iOS-SDK" is the name, I never start with 'lib' or end with it....

Comment: I guess something in the podspec is referencing a library incorrectly? I dunno, I just googled the error message.

Comment: I figure it out ! In my pod spec, " s.library = 'libbaidumapapi' ",that's the reason! Thanks for your help @Ant P